# Socket Timeout Exception in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat7, socket-timeout-exception

Getting socket timeout exception frequently in my web application. Let me explain what's the issue is while reading data at very first time application works fine and  according to my idea after some time it goes to ideal state. While executing it again(after some time), getting socket timeout error as mentioned below. Please help me in finding solution, Thank you.

```
 Dec 12, 2017 9:17:31 AM 
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not 
be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:535)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:504)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:566)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:431)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.StreamBasedParserBase.loadMore(StreamBasedParserBase.java:107)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._skipWS(Utf8StreamParser.java:1689)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:310)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.ArrayDeserializers$ByteDeser.deserialize(ArrayDeserializers.java:260)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.ArrayDeserializers$ByteDeser.deserialize(ArrayDeserializers.java:229)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:230)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:334)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:495)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:351)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2112)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1004)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:438)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

// Variables to build a client to call the Web Resource.
    Client c = Client.create();

```
// Declaring WebResource to connect to the web application
WebResource r =   
c.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(ReallyMakeConstants.URL_SERVER)
                .build());
MultivaluedMap<String, String> retrieveBidRequests = new 
MultivaluedMapImpl();
// Binding the values
retrieveBidRequests.add("vendorId", vendorId);
retrieveBidRequests.add("makeType", makeType);
retrieveBidRequests.add("selectedStatus", selectedBidStatus);

String veRequestsList = r.path("bidResource")
                    .path("retrieveVendorBidRequests2")
                    .queryParams(retrieveBidRequests)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);

String bidRequestsList = request
                                .getAttribute("veRequestsList ").toString();
JSONParser bidRequestJsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray bidRequestJsonArray;

BidRequest bidRequest = null;
Model model = null;

Object obj = bidRequestJsonParser.parse(bidRequestsList);
bidRequestJsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
```

Comment: This is caused by the client not sending data when the server expects it to.  There is not enough information to determine the root cause.

Comment: could you please tell me what is the required information to determine root cause of this exception?

Comment: Relevant source code for the client and server sides ...

Comment: Code updated ,could you please check once.